# C++ Pass entire list by reference

Tags: c++, list, pass-by-reference

I have the following piece of code:

```
void endConditionalFlowsBetweenSets(const list<unsigned int>& sourceSet, const     list<unsigned int>& endSet){
    //TODO: Optimize
    //ending previous flows between the two sets
    list<unsigned int>::iterator itS;
    list<unsigned int>::iterator itE;
    for(itS=sourceSet.begin();itS!=sourceSet.end();itS++)
        for(itE=endSet.begin();itE!=endSet.end();itE++)
            if(*itS!=*itE && linkIndex[*itS][*itE].index==-1)   
                endFlow(*itS,*itE);
}
```

Upon compilation I get the error: `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::list<unsigned int>::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator<unsigned int>}’ to ‘const std::_List_iterator<unsigned int>&’`

Why is that? I am just passing a list by reference and creating an iterator to iterate through it.

Comment: The iterators need to be `const` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > > *I am just passing a list by reference*

No, you are passing it by const reference. You have a `const` mismatch between your parameters and your iterators.

Either change the function signature:

```
void endConditionalFlowsBetweenSets(
    list<unsigned int>& sourceSet,
    list<unsigned int>& endSet);
```

or change the iterator delcarations:

```
 list<unsigned int>::const_iterator itS;
 list<unsigned int>::const_iterator itE;
```

Comment: Please upvote (click the upward-pointing triangle) the answers that helped you, and accept (click the check mark) one of them.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `const_iterator`:

```
 list<unsigned int>::const_iterator itS;
 list<unsigned int>::const_iterator itE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list `sourceSet` is const, but you are trying to create a non-const iterators. If you could do this, you'd be able to modify the list, which is no good since the list is `const`.

That's why you should be using `list<unsigned int>::const_iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `const_iterator`:

```
list<unsigned int>::const_iterator itS;
list<unsigned int>::const_iterator itE;
```

you are passing in `sourceSet` as `const` so you can not use non `const` iterators.

Answer (score 0):

This whole problem would never have happened if you just used `auto` and let the compiler find the appropriate types:

```
for(auto itS=sourceSet.begin(); itS!=sourceSet.end(); itS++)
    for(auto itE=endSet.begin(); itE!=endSet.end(); itE++)
        if(*itS!=*itE && linkIndex[*itS][*itE].index==-1)   
            endFlow(*itS,*itE);
```

You may also consider the range for loop

```
for(auto src : sourceSet)   // src is unsigned int
    for(auto&end : endSet)  // end is unsigned int&  allows manipulation in endFlow
        if(src != end && linkIndex[src][end].index==-1)
           endFlow(src,end);
```